# Redirect 301 from URL with question mark to new URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

Old url:
**example.com?archive&id=1133352540&start_from&subaction=showfull&ucat=2**

I would like to redirect it to:
**example.com/blog/post/**

I've tried various conditions in my .htaccess, nothing seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^archive&id=1133352540&start_from&subaction=showfull&ucat=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/post? [L,R=301]
```